# Ember set Component property in controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a Component, whose property I want to set in a Controller. I seem to be having problems using the computed alias to set it. Please see code below.

My Component is as follows:

```
 TM.MyModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    totalWidth: '200px',  
    widthStyle: function() { 
        console.log(this.get('totalWidth'));
        return 'width:'+this.get('totalWidth');    
    }.property('totalWidth'),  
 });
```

I am trying to set the property totalWidth in a parent controller as follows:

```
modalWidth:Ember.computed.alias("myModalComponent.totalWidth"),
this.set("modalWidth",'100px');
```

It returns a undefined value when I try to console log it and errors with
`Property set failed: object in path "myModalComponent" could not be found or was destroyed.`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you throw this up on jsbin?

Comment: parent's have no simple direct connection to their children's components.  Think if you put that component in the template twice, which one would be referenced by myModalComponent.  You would do something like this `{{ myModalComponent modalWidth=totalWidth}}`

Answer (score 1):

Refer this working example on fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/gXcfL/28/. Bind controller property to component's property in template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="container">
    <div>Click to set controller's width value</div>
    <button class="btn" {{action 'changeWidth'}}>Click</button>
    {{view TM.MyModalComponent 
     totalWidth = modalWidth
    }}
</div>
</script> 

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="component">
    {{widthStyle}}
</script>
```